# Cron not keeping to specified time

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I'm running crontab on Ubuntu 14.04, on DigitalOcean's VPS service.

I've made a web scraper to do a job every two hours.
My issue is, cron disregards the hours I've set and follows the minute instruction.

Here is my cron line

```
30 8,10,12,14,16 * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to/myscript.py
```

Instead of doing this job at 8.30am, 10.30am etc, this job ran at 11.30pm tonight. I changed the minutes to 37 and it ran again at 11.37pm.

Before running cron I changed the TZ to my time (Sydney), and when I'm logged into the VPS via the terminal, `date` returns my local time.

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: Try saving the output when job executes. Also try setting the `/usr/bin/python` path as the `shebang` of your script "`#!/usr/bin/python`". For log `30 8,10,12,14,16 * * * /path/to/myscript.py >> /path/to/log 2>&1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to save the answer from the comments:

The problem turned out to be that cron had started under one TZ value; afterwards, the TZ was changed (affecting future processes), but it was not until cron was restarted with the new TZ that cron jobs ran at the correct time.